# arp (where're my network devices?)

Tags: linux, arp

On linux there's `arp` command:

```
arp -n

Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.100            ether   00:55:d1:c5:f8:1b   C                     eth0
```

and

```
arp-scan -I eth0 -l

Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.2 00:1b:fc:35:6a:9b   ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.1.54    c8:d3:a6:34:d2:1d   (Unknown)
192.168.1.14    f0:25:b9:c2:6a:29   (Unknown)
```

Why I can't see correctly my devices?

I also have done:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

with `arp` command I see 1 device, with `arp-scan` I see other devices.

Does `arp` command read the cache, while `arp-scan` does a new scan (without reading any cache?)

Comment: Indeed, `arp` man page says "arp - manipulate the system ARP cache". So, there is no scan involved nor whatever. You only see the entries in the cache used recently.

Comment: Thanks Igeorget. Understood. So, what's the command to see devices actually alive?

Comment: I'm pretty sure arp-scan does what you want but usually, people[who?] tend to use higher-level scans[citation required], such as those performed by nmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Arp manipulates the kernel's ARP cache in various ways."

It's very nature is to read from a cache. From http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_arp.htm

Answer (score 3):

arp-scan is a completely different utility that actually scans. The linux 'arp' command only reads directly from the kernel's ARP cache. You can fake a scan using ping to populate the arp table.

Both are working exactly as they should be.

Not sure what you mean by "why I can't see correctly my devices?" those outputs are as they should be.